# Choose balanced records from a table due to a column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select records from a table which has a column with value -1 and +1
The ratio of -1 values to +1 values is about %17

But, I want to select records with balanced rate of -1 and +1 values.

For example I want to have select result with about %30 with -1 value and %70 with +1 value.

For example I have the following data set:

```
A B -1
A C -1
C Y +1
C A +1
C B +1
B C -1
A D +1
A F +1
D F +1
C F +1
```

Then, for example with %50 balanced data, I want to choose 4 records from these with exactly 2 records with value -1 and 2 records with value +1.

May you please help me how can I do this with SQL?

Thank you

Comment: please post sample data and expected result

Comment: can you explain the logic ? what do you mean by `50% balanced data` and which 4 records that you want in the result ?

Comment: Four records was an example. I want to have results of a select clause, which have %50 values of -1 and %50 values of +1

Comment: so for the `4 records` example, `%50 values of -1 and %50 values of +1`, how would the result looks like ?

Comment: For example: AB-1 / BC-1 / CF+1 / CB+1

Comment: based on what rules that you choose these 4 records and not the others ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you didn't state the rules required clearly i could only guess this is what you want.

```
declare 
    @percentage_1   int,
    @percentage_2   int,
    @recs           int,
    @rn             int,
    @rp             int


select  
    @percentage_1   = 50,
    @percentage_2   = 50,
    @recs           = 4

select  
    @rn     = @percentage_1 * @recs / 100,
    @rp     = @percentage_2 * @recs / 100

; with 
cte as
(
    select  *, r = row_number() over (partition by value order by col1, col2)
    from    your_table
)
select  *
from    cte
where   (value  = -1    and r   <= @rn)
or      (value  = +1    and r   <= @rp)
order by value, col1, col2
```

Comment: That was great. Thank you so much.